# Different declaration of hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I know that:

```
my %hash = {};
```

gets an anonymous hash, How about this:

```
my %hash = %{some values}
```

what is the difference of that above with this?

```
my %hash = (some hash values);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is how you express the content of the hash.
With the array notation below, for example; you do it like this:

```
my %hash = ( 'key 1' => 'value 1', 'key 2' => 'value 2');
```

The %{ } is a cast operator. It is used typically when you have a reference to something that is not obviously a hash. Typically a reference to a has:

Example:

```
my $hashref;
$hashref->{'key 1'}='value 1';
$hashref->{'key 2'}='value 2';
my %hash = %{$hashref};
```

Comment: can i use the same thing for arrays? like @()?

Comment: Yes. If you have an arrayref;  my $arrayref=[ 4, 5, 5]; $arrayref->[2]=2; my @array = @{$arrayref};

Answer (score 6):

No.

```
my %hash = {};
```

generates a warning (you turned them on, right?):

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1.
```

Reference is always scalar. The correct way is

```
my $hash_ref = {};
```

To dereference a reference, you can use the following syntax:

```
my %hash      = %$hash_ref;
my %also_hash = %{$hash_ref};          # Same as above.
$hash{key} eq $hash_ref->{key} or die; # Should survive.
```

Moreover,

```
%{ some values }
```

generates a syntax error:

```
perl -we 'my $h = %{1, 2, 3, 4}'
syntax error at -e line 1, near "%{"
```

Comment: yeah i forgot, it shoudlnt be %hash, its $hash. Thanks